# Click on a histogram bar to generate a scatterplot of the data in that bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

classes= ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5', 'class6', 'class7']
lens = [199, 30, 89, 59, 109, 115, 89]
nums = [145, 457, 123, 67, 35, 31, 134]

dict2 = {}

dict2['class1'] = [(2,2),(1,1),(2,3),(3,4),(5,1)]
dict2['class2'] = [(3,1),(4,4),(5,5),(6,2),(7,1)]
dict2['class3'] = [(3,2),(4,1),(5,4),(6,4),(7,1)]
dict2['class4'] = [(3,1),(4,5),(6,3),(4,3),(5,3)]
dict2['class5'] = [(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(4,3)]
dict2['class6'] = [(2,2),(2,1),(2,3),(5,3),(6,4)]


class1_dict = {}
class1_dict['xs'] = [i[0] for i in dict2['class1']]
class1_dict['ys'] = [i[1] for i in dict2['class1']]

dict_name = {}
dict_name['classes'] = classes
#dict_name['lens'] = lens
dict_name['nums'] = nums

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name, orient='columns')
print(df)
axs = df.hist(picker=True)
ax = axs[0, 0]

def onpick(event):
    bar = event.artist
    left = bar.get_x()
    right = left + bar.get_width()
    col_df = df[(df.nums >= left) & (df.nums <= right)].iloc[0] #change this, this is just for histogram
    points = dict2[col_df[0]] #change this i want a bar plot but trying to get this to work first
    class1_dict = {}
    class1_dict['xs'] = [i[0] for i in dict2['class1']]
    class1_dict['ys'] = [i[1] for i in dict2['class1']]
    plt.scatter(class1_dict['xs'],class1_dict['ys'])
    plt.show()

ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

#print(type(ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)))

plt.show()
```

The ultimate aim is to have a grouped bar chart of nums and lens of the data. You click on a bar, and it will bring you to a scatterplot of the data in that bar, the scatterplot data coming from `dict2`.

Firstly, in this example, I know a histogram is built and not a bar plot,  I'm not sure how to change the histogram to a bar plot, but it's not my biggest problem right now, so I've just added:

```
col_df = df[(df.nums >= left) & (df.nums <= right)].iloc[0] #change this, this is just for histogram
points = dict2[col_df[0]] #change this i want a bar plot but trying to get this to work first
```

to pretend that each bar is one class (which it's not in a histogram).

If I comment out:

```
#class1_dict = {}
#class1_dict['xs'] = [i[0] for i in dict2['class1']]
#class1_dict['ys'] = [i[1] for i in dict2['class1']]
#plt.scatter(class1_dict['xs'],class1_dict['ys']) 
#plt.show()
```

and instead add:

```
print(points)
```

I can click on a bar in the histogram, and it will return the points that make up that bar, e.g. `[(3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 2), (7, 1)]` was returned.

I want to then produce them on a scatterplot, so I added in the code I commented out above to generate a scatterplot. However, there's no error, but there's also no scatterplot produced. Without an error to guide I'm not sure where to go next, I'm wondering am I not able to have `plt.show()` twice in one piece of code (I thought it would just open a new window)?

Comment: The first thing I would try is to create the different figures and axes explicitly instead of relying on pandas/pyplot to (hopefully) manage that for you

Comment: Thanks a mil, I can do that (assuming I'm understanding what you're saying), if you take the scatterplot section into a separate piece of code, it will generate the scatterplot, so both figures are generated when each piece of code is run separately (but let me know if i've mis-understood this).

Comment: I'm wondering if this can be done in bokeh, that's what I'm researching at the minute (I'm not an expert in any visualisation library, so don't tied down to using a particular one).

Comment: Well, your code does produce a scatterplot. It is very hard to see as it uses the same axes as the histogram, making its points squashed together at the left.  You could call `plt.figure()` just before `plt.scatter()` to create a new figure on top. Or you could call `plt.cla()` to erase the histogram, if that is preferred. Or maybe you want two subplots, with the histogram at the left and a scatter plot at the right?